# Problem with dockerizing a Django project with Celery and RabbitMQ

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to dockerize my Django project with Celery and RabbitMQ. I have a Docker Compose file, but I am having trouble getting it to work.

Here is my Docker Compose file:

```yaml
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest

  celery_worker:
    image: python:3.10
    command: celery -A zwitter worker -l INFO
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - app
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/
    networks:
      - main
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - cache:/data
    command: redis-server --save 60 1
    restart: always

  app:
    image: python:3.10
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/src/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

networks:
  main:

volumes:
  cache:
```

When I try to start the Docker Compose containers, everything works fine and the containers are all up. But when any celery task is about to run in my django project, I get the following error:

```
[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I have tried all of the following, but the problem still persists:

- Making sure that the RabbitMQ server is running and accessible.
- Making sure that the Celery worker is configured to connect to the correct RabbitMQ server.
- Checking the network connection between the Celery worker container and the RabbitMQ server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two containers to connect to each other, they have to be on the same Docker network.  Two of your containers (`rabbitmq` and `celery_worker`) are explicitly attached to `networks: [main]`, but the other two (`redis` and `app`) aren't.  For these two containers, Compose creates a network named `default` and attaches them to it.

The easiest solution here is to delete *all* of the `networks:` blocks from the file.  Compose will attach all of the containers to the automatically-created `default` network.  Since they'll all be on the same network, DNS resolution will work as expected.

(This is probably not your problem, but for the two containers you `build: .`, you should also delete the `image: python:3.10` lines, and then manually `docker pull python:3.10` once.  If you have both `build:` and `image:` then this sets the name of the image that gets built, which means that your image builds are actually appending to the previous build and not starting from a clean Python base image.)